# Game Oriented Assembly Lisp

Tags: lisp

I've been reading about Game Oriented Assembly Lisp (written by Andy Gavin in Allegro CL, used in Naughty Dog dev. work before the Sony purchase), and I was wondering if there's any way to find a version of it or something similar. I know it's a proprietary language, so the answer might be a resounding 'no', but thanks anyway.

*edit: I've noticed that GOAL is also the name of another language for agent programming.  Sorry for any confusion due to the title.*

Comment: i just have to upvote this because "game oriented assembly lisp" sounds so scary/crazy/awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://all-things-andy-gavin.com/goal-test/) is stated that the code belongs to SONY, and thus, it isn't available.